# Problema al asignar valor a propiedades de User Control en vb .Net

Tags: vb.net, usercontrol

Tengo un user control en el que le implemento la siguiente interface:

```
Public Interface IPropiedades
    Property NombreUsuario() As String
    Property LabelInstancia() As String
    Property NombreInstancia() As String
    Property EstacionTrabajo() As String
    Property Periodo() As String
    Property Status() As String
End Interface
```

En el UC lo implemento de la sig. manera:

```
Public Class UC_StatusControlBar
    Implements IPropiedades
    Public Property NombreUsuario As String Implements IPropiedades.NombreUsuario
    Public Property LabelInstancia As String Implements IPropiedades.LabelInstancia    
    Public Property NombreInstancia As String Implements IPropiedades.NombreInstancia 
    Public Property EstacionTrabajo As String Implements IPropiedades.EstacionTrabajo
    Public Property Periodo As String Implements IPropiedades.Periodo
    Public Property Status As String Implements IPropiedades.Status

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

Private Sub UC_StatusControlBar_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load       
        lbl_nombreinstancia.Text = NombreInstancia
    End Sub
End Class
```

Ahora se supone, que donde yo le seteo al label lo que valga la propiedad de ese control de usuario lo tendría que mostrar justo cuando se carga (por el evento Load)

Pero cuando yo lo uso en un Winform

Puedo acceder a sus propiedades tanto en el diseño como a nivel de codigo

```
UC_StatusControlBar.NombreInstancia = "Algo"
```

El problema es que cuando corro el formulario aparece en blanco osea no me lo muestra, excepto si por diseño en el cuadro de propiedades del control si le pongo un valor por default ahí si lo enseña.

Quiero saber si alguien podría decirme que me hace falta o que estoy haciendo mal. Muchas gracias.

Comment: podes explicar un poco mejor el problema? lo que pareces decir no parece un error si no el funcionamiento correcto..

Comment: @gbianchi es correcto, no lo hago ver como un error si no más bien ayuda para entender que estoy haciendo mal. Lo quiero decir básicamente es que porque cuando agrego el control al formulario y dentro del codigo en la instancia que hago sobre ese control y accediendo a las propiedades le seteo un valor, este cambio no lo veo reflejado a la hora que corro mi aplicación.

Comment: Tu problema es que no esta guardando la propiedad en el control de Usuario?

Comment: @gbianchi es correcto, no me guardaba la propiedad y al parecer encontré la respuesta y la acabo de publicar, más tarde entro a aceptar la respuesta como buena. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He encontrado la solución:

No puedo asignar (por alguna razón que aún no comprendo ni sé) los valores de las propiedades en cualquier otro lado de mi winform que no sea en el constructor.

Según VisualStudio no funciona esto:

```
Private Sub MainSIB_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        UC_StatusControlBar1.NombreInstancia = "Algo"
End Sub
```

Pero si en el constructor:

```
 Public Sub New()

        ' Esta llamada es exigida por el diseñador.
        InitializeComponent()
        UC_StatusControlBar1.NombreInstancia = "algo"
        UC_StatusControlBar1.NombreUsuario = "Axel"
        ' Agregue cualquier inicialización después de la llamada a InitializeComponent().

 End Sub
```

Espero le sirva a alguien. Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Buenisimo!!!! recuerda aceptarla en 24 horas!